# How to show that a console.groupCollapsed() contains an error?

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log

I use `console.groupCollapsed()` to structure my console messages but it always looks the same (Firefox Developer Edition 66.0b8). However console messages look different based on the log level, i.e. a warning is highlighted and an error even more. How can I show the user that a certain console group contains a warning or an error? This could be through either opening the group or by color coding the group opening line based on the "worst" statement it contains.

**Example**

```
console.groupCollapsed("Everything OK here");
console.log("Function A succeeded");
console.groupEnd();

console.groupCollapsed("We got a problem here");
console.log("Function B succeeded");
console.error("Function C failed");
console.groupEnd();
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to the Firefox Devtools.

Comment: @Bergi: I only tested it on Firefox but it should work on all major browsers. Also there may be some JavaScript functionality that allows me to implement this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I don't think you will have any control over the color coding from within the website.

Comment: @Bergi: Alternatively, opening the group would be acceptable. Is there any functionality to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a 100% solution, but you can adjust the colors of a group to closer look like what an error would look like. It can be done using the `%c` directive.

You can find a bit of documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#styling_console_output

Although they don't explicitly mention styling groups, you can apply the same directive to `console.group`.

```
console.group(
  '%cSomething bad happened',
  'color: #dd9ab5; background-color: #4b2f36',
); 
console.log('something else'); 
console.warn('a warning'); 
console.error('an error'); 
console.groupEnd();
```

[image]